# How do i create an option in switch case?

Tags: switch-statement, case

I've recently tried to make some switch case function. Now, I'm currently trying to make an option but it seems it always skips the if part in case 1.  The input just doesn't go in the if - else part.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

```
int option;
char choice;
int celcius;
menu:
printf("Welcome to program.\n");
printf("1. Input celcius\n");
printf("2. Convert To Kelvin\n");
printf("3. Convert To Fahrenheit\n");
printf("4. Convert To Reamur\n");


scanf("%d", &option);

    switch(option){
    case 1:
        scanf("%d", &celcius);
        printf("The value is : %d\n", celcius);
        printf("Continue? : (y/n)\n"); scanf("%c", &choice);getchar();
        
        
        if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
            goto menu;
        }else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N');
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        printf("Please input the value: "); scanf("%d", &celcius);
        int kelvin = celcius + 273;
        printf("Converted Value is : %d\n", kelvin);
        break;  
    case 3:
        printf("Please input the value: "); scanf("%d", &celcius);
        int fahrenheit = celcius + 32;
        printf("Converted Value is : %d\n", fahrenheit);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Please input the value: "); scanf("%d", &celcius);
        int reamur = 5/4 * celcius;
        printf("Converted Value is : %d\n", reamur);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
}

return 0;
```

}
(incomplete code because currently trying to make the case 1 works.)
Any solutions will help : )

Comment: It's probably not skipping the `if` it's that the choice value does not match any of y,Y,n or N. Try printing the value of choice (as a char) using `printf(...)` before there and see.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `getchar()` after the `scanf()` for `choice`. This is reading the newline character that is left in the input buffer after the `scanf()` for `option`.
You need to remove the `getchar()` and change the `scanf()` for `choice` to:

```cpp
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

The space before the `%c` will skip any whitespace characters in the input buffer.